# Design Automation Timeout Error When plotting PDF

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have an issue here with Forge Design Automation, input is DWG, then I am manipulating it, and finally generating Plot Plan PDF as a result, and it throughs a timeout error at the printing code although LimitProcessingTimeSec is set as 900 and the work item does not take more than 1 minute.
Its weird as the error is timeout although the the whole task is failing in just 1 minute, so seems exporting PDF is causing timeout for this big community although the big timeout we put for the work item.

Can you help me please on that ? Is there anything specific for PDF printing to increase its timeout?

Here is last part of the DA report

`[12/27/2023 08:02:57] Effective plotting area: 23.37 wide by 34.59 high

[12/27/2023 08:02:57] Effective plotting area: 18.66 wide by 28.37 high

[12/27/2023 08:02:57] Plotting viewport 2.

[12/27/2023 08:04:00] Error: AutoCAD Core Console is shut down due to timeout.

[12/27/2023 08:04:00] End script phase.

[12/27/2023 08:04:00] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.

[12/27/2023 08:04:00] Job finished with result FailedExecution`